# WPF - Drag & Drop file extract icon and convert to bitmap (show on button or other object)

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm working with WPF, and trying to implement a form to receive a Drag and Drop link, and assign to a button on a record (attach links to files to a record).

I can get the link path with no issue.  I'm stuck trying to extract the icon file from the link, and convert and render it.

```
    private void frmMain_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] sFileList = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (String sFilename in sFileList)
        {

            String sNew = sFilename;
        }
    }
```

That is what I have so far.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
myImageControl.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(sFilename));
```

Where `myImageControl` is an `Image` declared somewhere in your application's XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="myImageControl" />
```